# Jquery namepsace not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

I have inherited a jquery component that simulates a dropdown for users to choose an option from.

The component can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/Qg9f4/2/ and it seems to work fine.

However, we are trying to namespace all of our scripts into a single file. In general, this works fine as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707076/jquery-and-javascript-namepsace). However, this component stops working when we use the same technique for namespacing. The init script seems to parse fine on $(document).ready, but nothing actually happens when the component is clicked.

I have commented in the jsfiddle as to what does and does not work.

**This works**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".dselector dt a").click(function () {
        $(".dselector dd ul").toggle();
    });

    $(".dselector dd ul li a").click(function () {
        $(".dselector dd ul").hide();
    });

    $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dselector")) $(".dselector dd ul").hide();
    });
});
```

**This doesnt work**

```
$(document).ready(zxcf.init());

var zxcf = {
    init: function() {
        $(".dselector dt a").click(function () {
            $(".dselector dd ul").toggle();
        });

        $(".dselector dd ul li a").click(function () {
            $(".dselector dd ul").hide();
        });

        $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dselector")) $(".dselector dd ul").hide();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Please post your code here. I hate having to go to jsFiddle to see what's being asked.

Comment: code added to above post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `zxcf` variable ***before*** you've initialized it.

This means that the `ready()` handler will be invoked right away, and so the `zxcf` is not yet intialized.

http://jsfiddle.net/UtSmC/

```
var zxcf = {
    init: function() {
        $(".dselector dt a").click(function () {
            $(".dselector dd ul").toggle();
        });

        $(".dselector dd ul li a").click(function () {
            $(".dselector dd ul").hide();
        });

        $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dselector")) $(".dselector dd ul").hide();
        });
    }
};

$(document).ready(zxcf.init); // <-- pass it instead of invoking it
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UtSmC/

***Also***, you're *invoking* the function instead of passing it to `.ready()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using `zxcf` variable before even defining it. You should define your namespace first and then use it. Try this.

```
var zxcf = {
    init: function() {
        $(".dselector dt a").click(function () {
            $(".dselector dd ul").toggle();
        });

        $(".dselector dd ul li a").click(function () {
            $(".dselector dd ul").hide();
        });

        $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dselector")) $(".dselector dd ul").hide();
        });
    }
};
$(document).ready(zxcf.init);
```

Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qg9f4/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Call the document.ready function after you initialize the variable, as shown below

```
var zxcf = {
init: function() {
    $(".dselector dt a").click(function () {
        $(".dselector dd ul").toggle();
    });

    $(".dselector dd ul li a").click(function () {
        $(".dselector dd ul").hide();
    });

    $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dselector")) $(".dselector dd ul").hide();
    });
}
};

$(document).ready(function(){zxcf.init()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your a calling `$.ready()` with ready with `zxcf.init()`. But you deglare `zxcf` after this. So when you call `$.ready()`, `zxcf` is undefined, and will cause an error when you try do call a `init` on undefined. The problem is that you store the function in a variable instead to use a named function:

```
$(document).ready(zxcf.init);

function zxcf () {
    this.init= function() {
        $(".dselector dt a").click(function () {
            $(".dselector dd ul").toggle();
        });

        $(".dselector dd ul li a").click(function () {
            $(".dselector dd ul").hide();
        });

        $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dselector")) $(".dselector dd ul").hide();
        });
    }
};
```

Or you deglare your variable before call `ready`:

```
var zxcf = {
    init: function() {
        $(".dselector dt a").click(function () {
            $(".dselector dd ul").toggle();
        });

        $(".dselector dd ul li a").click(function () {
            $(".dselector dd ul").hide();
        });

        $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dselector")) $(".dselector dd ul").hide();
        });
    }
};

$(document).ready(zxcf.init);
```